# mainmenu in 2dgame not loading just black screen

Tags: java, android, andengine

i'm trying to build a 2d game and now after i created the main menu and all of it supplies i'm having a problem with loading the main menu whenever i start the app just a black screen is appearing and main menu isn't i think i have done the steps for creating them probably but i can't figure out what's the error i hope you can help me

this is the logcat

```
02-15 13:05:10.437: E/dalvikvm(4253): 4253 :: IS_UNIFIED_ARM_PROCESS=FALSE, debugFlags = 3
02-15 13:05:10.657: D/AndEngine(4253): MainGameActivity.onCreate @(Thread: 'main')
02-15 13:05:10.657: D/dalvikvm(4253): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.example.dgame/lib/libandengine.so 0xb3033500
02-15 13:05:10.657: D/dalvikvm(4253): Added shared lib /data/data/com.example.dgame/lib/libandengine.so 0xb3033500
02-15 13:05:10.657: D/dalvikvm(4253): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.example.dgame/lib/libandengine.so 0xb3033500, skipping init
02-15 13:05:10.717: D/AndEngine(4253): MainGameActivity.onResume @(Thread: 'main')
02-15 13:05:10.747: D/libEGL(4253): egl.cfg not found, using default config
02-15 13:05:10.747: D/libEGL(4253): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_bst.so
02-15 13:05:10.747: W/PGA(4253): eglGetProcAddress: "eglGetRenderBufferANDROID" not  found
02-15 13:05:10.747: W/PGA(4253): eglGetProcAddress: "eglGetSystemTimeFrequencyNV" not   found
02-15 13:05:10.747: W/PGA(4253): eglGetProcAddress: "eglGetSystemTimeNV" not found
02-15 13:05:10.777: I/PGA(4253): New SOCKET connection: m.example.dgame (pid 4253, tid 4270)
02-15 13:05:10.817: I/PGA(4253): New SOCKET connection: m.example.dgame (pid 4253, tid 4253)
02-15 13:05:10.997: D/AndEngine(4253): VERSION: OpenGL ES 2.0
02-15 13:05:10.997: D/AndEngine(4253): RENDERER: Bluestacks
02-15 13:05:10.997: D/AndEngine(4253): EGLCONFIG: EGLConfig(Red=5, Green=6, Blue=5, Alpha=0, Depth=0, Stencil=0)
02-15 13:05:10.997: D/AndEngine(4253): EXTENSIONS: GL_OES_EGL_image      
GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_OES_blend_func_separate 
GL_OES_blend_equation_separate GL_OES_blend_subtract GL_OES_byte_coordinates   
GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_point_size_array GL_OES_point_sprite   
GL_OES_single_precision GL_OES_stencil_wrap GL_OES_texture_env_crossbar          GL_OES_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_texture_cube_map    GL_OES_draw_texture GL_OES_framebuffer_object GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32     GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_stencil1 GL_OES_stencil4 GL_OES_stencil8 GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888   GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture 
02-15 13:05:10.997: D/AndEngine(4253): MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS: 16
02-15 13:05:10.997: D/AndEngine(4253): MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS: 256
02-15 13:05:10.997: D/AndEngine(4253): MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS: 256
02-15 13:05:10.997: D/AndEngine(4253): MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS: 32
02-15 13:05:10.997: D/AndEngine(4253): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
02-15 13:05:10.997: D/AndEngine(4253): MainGameActivity.onSurfaceCreated @(Thread: 'GLThread 121')
02-15 13:05:10.997: D/AndEngine(4253): MainGameActivity.onCreateGame @(Thread: 'GLThread 121')
02-15 13:05:11.017: D/AndEngine(4253): MainGameActivity.onCreateResources @(Thread: 'GLThread 121')
02-15 13:05:11.027: D/AndEngine(4253): MainGameActivity.onSurfaceChanged(Width=1066,  Height=552) @(Thread: 'GLThread 121')
02-15 13:05:28.407: E/dalvikvm(4253): No JIT support for bytecode f0 at offsetPC 0
02-15 13:05:28.407: E/dalvikvm(4253): JIT implementation not found
02-15 13:05:28.407: I/dalvikvm(4253): codeGenBasicBlockJit returns negative number
02-15 13:05:47.557: D/AndEngine(4253): MainGameActivity.onPause @(Thread: 'main')
02-15 13:05:49.857: D/AndEngine(4253): MainGameActivity.onResume @(Thread: 'main')
02-15 13:05:49.917: D/AndEngine(4253): VERSION: OpenGL ES 2.0
02-15 13:05:49.917: D/AndEngine(4253): RENDERER: Bluestacks
02-15 13:05:49.917: D/AndEngine(4253): EGLCONFIG: EGLConfig(Red=5, Green=6, Blue=5, Alpha=0, Depth=0, Stencil=0)
02-15 13:05:49.917: D/AndEngine(4253): EXTENSIONS: GL_OES_EGL_image GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_OES_blend_func_separate GL_OES_blend_equation_separate GL_OES_blend_subtract GL_OES_byte_coordinates GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_point_size_array GL_OES_point_sprite GL_OES_single_precision GL_OES_stencil_wrap GL_OES_texture_env_crossbar GL_OES_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_texture_cube_map GL_OES_draw_texture GL_OES_framebuffer_object GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_stencil1 GL_OES_stencil4 GL_OES_stencil8 GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture 
02-15 13:05:49.917: D/AndEngine(4253): MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS: 16
02-15 13:05:49.917: D/AndEngine(4253): MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS: 256
02-15 13:05:49.917: D/AndEngine(4253): MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS: 256
02-15 13:05:49.917: D/AndEngine(4253): MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS: 32
02-15 13:05:49.917: D/AndEngine(4253): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
```

and this is the mainmenu.java

```
package com.example.dgame;

import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.menu.MenuScene;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.menu.MenuScene.IOnMenuItemClickListener;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.menu.item.IMenuItem;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.menu.item.SpriteMenuItem;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.menu.item.decorator.ScaleMenuItemDecorator;
import org.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.andengine.opengl.util.GLState;

import com.example.dgame.SceneManager.SceneType;

public class MainMenu extends BaseScene implements IOnMenuItemClickListener{


private MenuScene menuChildScene;
private final int PLAY = 0;

@Override
public void createScene() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    this.attachChild(new Sprite(0,0,resourceManager.mainMenuBackground,vbom){

        @Override
        protected void preDraw(GLState pGLState, Camera pCamera){
            super.preDraw(pGLState, pCamera);
            pGLState.enableDither();

        }

    });


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public SceneType getSceneType() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void disposeScene() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void createMenuScene(){


    this.menuChildScene = new MenuScene(camera);

    this.menuChildScene.setPosition(0, 0);

    final IMenuItem playMenuItem = new ScaleMenuItemDecorator(new 
                    SpriteMenuItem(this.PLAY,resourceManager.playButton,vbom),1.2f,1);


    this.menuChildScene.addMenuItem(playMenuItem);

    menuChildScene.buildAnimations();
    menuChildScene.setBackgroundEnabled(false);

    menuChildScene.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);

    this.setChildScene(menuChildScene, false, true, true);

}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClicked(MenuScene pMenuScene, IMenuItem pMenuItem,
        float pMenuItemLocalX, float pMenuItemLocalY) {

    switch(pMenuItem.getID()){

    case PLAY:
        //load game
        return true;

    default:
        return false;



    }


}
    }
```

and this is the maingameactivity.java

```
package com.example.dgame;

import org.andengine.engine.Engine;
import org.andengine.engine.LimitedFPSEngine;
import org.andengine.engine.camera.BoundCamera;
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.FillResolutionPolicy;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;


 public class MainGameActivity extends BaseGameActivity {

private BoundCamera camera;

private float WIDTH = 800;
private float HEIGHT = 480;


@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine(EngineOptions engineOptions){

    return new LimitedFPSEngine(engineOptions,60);

}

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {

    camera = new BoundCamera(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);

    EngineOptions engineOptions = new
            EngineOptions(true,ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED,new  FillResolutionPolicy(),camera);
```

Comment: Can you show all code of `maingameactivity.java`?

Comment: In `maingameactivity.java` file, you need create a scene in `public void onCreateScene`.